# How place several monitors in parallel?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

How can I place three monitors in parallel? There is one DVI output on the graphics card. How have the output displayed on three monitors simultaneously?

What extra hardware is required?

Apparently I needed to look for a "DVI-splitter."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We bought a (VGA) display extender that takes the video + audio signals over up to 95m of Cat 5. As an added bonus, the receiver end of the kit has 4 outputs that can be used simultaneously so this kind of approach may be viable if the displays all need to be close to each other.

A Google search for "DVI extender 4 port" also brings up a lot of kit.

Answer (score 0):

i believe a matrox triplehead-2-go is able to do this. What you're looking for is called sceeen "cloning" or "cloned" mode of operation.

Comment: Thank you. I looked at that card, but it's overkill, since I only need to have the same signal sent to three monitors, not different signals to each.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in this excellent [post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/06/multiple-monitors-and-productivity.html) by Jeff, you'll require another PCI video card for a new monitor. Note that you could get a dual-headed video card, so you'll need only one more card for your extra monitors.

As Jeff notes, make sure you check this [Multi-Monitor FAQ](http://www.realtimesoft.com/multimon/faq.asp), and search their [compatibility database](http://www.realtimesoft.com/multimon/search.asp) to ensure that your new video card will work.

Comment: Not when I want the same signal on three monitors. My use of "parallel" was unfortunate.